# Image url 404 error in img tag

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

Strange problem!!

I am trying to display an image in my laravel application after an ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
                url:$(this).attr('action'),
                method:"post",
                processData:false,
                contentType: false,
                data:data,
                success:function (data) {
                   console.log(data.url);
                   $('#cropped-image').attr('src', encodeURI(data.url));

                 }
```

But i got `404` error in console however when i open the url in browser it will download the image.

Image is upload via s3 direct browser upload

```
<form id="upload" action="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lambdacushbu" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201" />
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="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" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-credential" value="AKIAJU45T7UWSXBGSY/20170327/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-date" value="20170327T083822Z" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-signature" value="2b89cf3b21de2a118f24c0f9b8463025615d302f86ee85047adc9bbf0cccee97" />
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="image">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload">
        <span id="status-text"></span>
</form>
```

anonymous read permission  is added to the bucket policy page

Comment: So if you `console.log(encodeURI(data.url))` and copy the url from the console, it works?

Comment: Yes it works fine